# Comparar o valor de uma célular com o nome de uma aba em VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Estou com o seguinte problema: Tenho 2 abas uma denominada **"Lista"** onde estão os nomes dos funcionários e o cargo que cada um ocupa, essa lista com nomes muda mensalmente, como exemplo
**Funcionário A - Cargo 1** /
**Funcionário B - Cargo 2**

Possa ser que no mês seguinte a lista mude para:
**Funcionário D - Cargo 2**/
**Funcionário H - Cargo 10**

Essa lista é previamente determinada para cada mês.

A segunda aba se chama **"Base"** nela está o nome do funcionário, a data que o funcionário trabalhou naquele projeto, a quantidade de horas e a descrição da atividade exercida. Ainda dentro dessa planilha há diversas abas nomeadas de acordo com o cargo, ou seja, tem-se a aba Cargo 1, Cargo 2, etc. O que eu preciso fazer, por meio de VBA é verificar na aba **"Lista"** o nome do funcionário e o cargo que ele ocupa e ir na aba **"Base"** copiar as informações referentes a data, duração trabalhada e descrição do trabalho daquele funcionário da lista e alocar exatamente na aba referente ao cargo que ele está ocupando naquele mês. Mas existem duas condicionantes nessa cópia, dentro da aba do cargo devem aparecer as datas entre 21/[mês anterior] e 20/[mês posterior] em ordem, mesmo que o funcionário não tenha trabalhado naquela data e quando as datas datas aparecerem duplicadas, copiar a duplicidade colocando a mesma data uma embaixo da outra.

Answer (score 0):

Para te ajudar com essa situação, eu queria, por favor, levantar os seguintes pontos:

- Como o nome dos funcionários na aba "Lista" é atualizada? Alguém copia e cola os nomes a cada mês ou algo assim?
- Se sim, para trazer a relação de dados de cada funcionário na aba "Lista", uma função PROCV já resolve seu problema
- Poderia explicar (e se possível, mostrar imagens) sobre as condicionantes apontadas no final?

Agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Na aba Lista o preenchimento é feito por um funcionário, eu criei uma lista com o nome de todos os funcionários e todos o cargos, o funcionário que vai mexer na planilha ele cadasta o nome da pessoa ao cargo que ela está ocupando naquele mês.

Answer (score 0):

Olá. Adaptei uma planilha como sugestão pra atender as suas necessidades seguindo seus requisitos.

Você deve cadastrar os funcionários como normalmente faz, na planilha Lista.
Quanto aos cargos, você deverá cadastrar na planilha Cargos.

Em seguida você faz os lançamentos através da planilha Lançamentos, onde você escolherá o funcionário de acordo com a lista e automaticamente o cargo atual dele será carregado. Quando clicar no botão Lançar os dados serão registrados na planilha Base.

[image: Lançamento]

Agora para resolver o problema de cada planilha para cargos que você tinha, criei apenas uma planilha Relatorio, onde você pode escolher o cargo desejado e o período de apuração. Coloque a data de 21 a 20 do outro mês como você havia dito. Ao clicar em processar, o código irá buscar todos os lançamentos neste período e deste cargo na planilha Base e apresentá-los na ordem que você disse precisar.

[image: Relatório de Cargos]

Uma ressalva é que, se você deseja que todas as datas sem atividades apareçam no relatório, deverá fazer um lançamento apenas com data e cargo.

Não me preocupei com tratamento de erros e formatação total. Poderá melhorar com o tempo. Segue o link do arquivo no GitHub:

[https://github.com/clovisdanielcosta/excel-vba/tree/master/src/Cargos e Atividades.xlsm](https://github.com/clovisdanielcosta/excel-vba/tree/master/src)

Espero que ajude.

Abraços.